# Jade template not found on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, pug

Running [this](https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-14838632) Express app locally *works*. Running it on [Heroku](http://heroku-node-express-test.herokuapp.com/nested) gives the pasted error when requesting either `/` or `/nested`

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index"
    at Function.app.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:493:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:753:7)
    at /app/server.js:21:16
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
    at store.get.next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:309:9)

Error: Failed to lookup view "nested/index"
    at Function.app.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:493:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:753:7)
    at /app/server.js:24:16
    at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:161:37)
    at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:135:11)
    at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:142:5)
    at Router._dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:170:5)
    at Object.router (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:33:10)
    at next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:199:15)
    at store.get.next (/app/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:309:9)
```

In my server file:

```
express = require 'express'
app = express()

app.configure () ->

  app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'
  app.set 'view engine', 'jade'

  app.use express.logger('dev')
  app.use express.bodyParser()
  app.use express.methodOverride()
  app.use express.cookieParser()
  app.use express.session(
    secret: 'WTF'
  )
  app.use app.router
  app.use express['static'](process.cwd() + '/public')

  app.get '/', (req, res) ->

    res.render 'index'

  app.get '/nested', (req, res) ->

    res.render 'nested/index'

port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen port, () -> 
  console.log 'Server started on ' + port + '\nPress CTRL-C to stop server.'
```

Locally, I do *not* need to specify `app.set 'views', __dirname + '/views'` for the server to run and find the files - it does not work on Heroku with or without this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your edit:

The issue may be case. While the strings specify lower-case paths:

- [`res.render 'index'`](https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-14838632/blob/3c9f3610d28454cb60f9bdfe76e4b1c1a73ea98a/src/server/server.coffee#L21)
- [`res.render 'nested/index'`](https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-14838632/blob/3c9f3610d28454cb60f9bdfe76e4b1c1a73ea98a/src/server/server.coffee#L25)

The files are actually capitalized:

- [`views/Index.jade`](https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-14838632/blob/3c9f3610d28454cb60f9bdfe76e4b1c1a73ea98a/views/Index.jade)
- [`views/nested/Index.jade`](https://github.com/franklovecchio/stackoverflow-14838632/blob/3c9f3610d28454cb60f9bdfe76e4b1c1a73ea98a/views/nested/Index.jade)

Your local system appears to be using a case-insensitive file system while Heroku does not.

---

---

To help Express find your views, you can set a `'views'` root path:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
```

You may also be able to pass an absolute path to `res.render()`:

```
res.render(__dirname + '/views/admin/login');
```

---

Also note that you probably don't need (and may not want) to pass `req` and `res` to [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render):

```
app.get('/admin/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('admin/login');
});
```

With them, the properties of `req` will be included as `locals` in the view and `res` as the `callback` will either be ignored or cause an error since it's not a `function`.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I was able to clean up the app and reproduce the issue, even with your suggested fix. See the above for links to code / Heroku app.

Comment: @FrankLoVecchio The issue may be the case in the strings vs. the case in the file names. See my edit.

Comment: I didn't even think of that! Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but I've followed all the suggestions here to no avail. :( Any new ideas? Everything works like a charm locally but after pushing to Heroku only the index view can be found. Super weird!